# Abstract Base Class w/o Polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

Why would you have an abstract base class defining an interface for a library where there is only one (always and forever) derived class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to swap out the implementation for something like Unit Testing

Comment: Are you saying where I'd have something like class Foo : public Base and class FooTest : public Base and I'd instantiate FooTest in a unit testing program that might have stubbed functionality?

Comment: Yes, or use a mocking framework like googlemock to do it for you

Comment: You can do that without having a special interface by just extending the used class (which also means that you can reuse already existing functionality).

Answer (score 3):

One reason why you would do this is for testability.  It is much simpler to test dependent objects when their dependencies are defined as interfaces.  This give the easy ability to mock or stub.

Comment: Past that, I cannot think of a good reason unless you consider IOC and Dependency injection. Is is possible that this class could change it's implementation later, without changing the signatures?

Comment: Maybe that's just me, but isn't it usually easier (and less errorprone) to extend the class itself and add some methods (or constructor) to set private variables for the testing? Or if I want to add logging I can just as easily overwrite the methods, handle the logging and call the super class. Without that you have to implement the common functionality twice, which sounds like a bad idea imo.

Comment: I usually work in .NET, so I prefer setting the expectations on my mocks and then replaying the behavior.  In c++, this may be entirely different.

Comment: You don't have to write otherwise-pointless interfaces to do this. You can mock concrete classes too (as long as they aren't sealed, and the methods that you want to mock are `virtual`).

Comment: Ok in C# (contrary to Java or c++) you may run into the problem that methods are per default sealed which is problematic for this (and making all methods virtual isn't especially nice coding style in c# and you may not even have control over the class). But even if you want to replace the complete Implementation of a class you don't need an interface just as Jason says. And often enough there is quite a lot of functionality in the class that I can reuse this way.

Answer (score 2):

To violate the [reused abstraction principle](http://www.codemanship.co.uk/parlezuml/blog/?postid=934).

In short, don't do this.

Those who say "for testing" are overlooking that you can just replace

```
Base < - > Derived
Base < - > DerivedForMockingAndTesting
```

with

```
Derived < - > DerivedForMockingAndTesting
```

That is, let your existing implementation `Derived` serve as the "abstraction" to be mocked out and tested in unit testing.

Comment: What if the constructor of `Derived` does something that you don't want the mock to do?

Comment: Or has non-virtual functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you can be 100% certain that there will always be only one and exactly one derived class? Not much reason. BUT: In reality you hardly will be 100% certain of anything and surely not the future of your code.

Comment: You also can't be certain the abstraction you come up with will be the right one if you meet that uncertain future point where you have to implement it a second time.

Comment: @Jason Sure, you may very well find out that your interfaces have serious problems on their own. So while you don't get rid of ALL problems, you get rid of one at least. And just to add an example of exactly the problem Jason brings up: If you look around many grown frameworks you'll find interfaces with names like X2 which were created in exactly such situations (horrible crutch but still better than what you'd have to do if you had used classes!).

Answer (score 1):

You may find the need for different versions of that class to be binary compatible. You may also find that for other reasons, you wish to encapsulate the definition of the class- for example, because the definition requires a header which has poor macros, and that kind of thing, or the header containing what's necessary to define the class has a very long compile time.

For example, I wrote a class to encapsulate the features offered by my operating system- for now, things like dynamic loading and creating a window. Even though there'll only ever be one implementation for one compile target (Windows, etc), I chose to use a run-time abstraction, because I wanted to guarantee that the rest of my code never saw a platform-specific header, and the Windows header is full of so many macros and stuff, that I didn't want them leaking out.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious reason would be to be able to put the class'
implementation in a source file, and not in a header.  All that is
exposed in the header is the abstract base class (and a factory function
necessary to construct it, but this could be a static member).  This
avoids having to include the header files for any member data; the pimpl
idiom is more idiomatic in C++ for this, but using abstract classes like
this is far from unknown, and works fairly well as well.